# DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133/1) Potentially related to NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists?

Tags: wdk, windows-kernel, ndis

We have a NDIS LWF driver, and on a single machine we get a `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION 133/1` bugcheck when they try to connect to their VPN to connect to the internet. This could be related to our `NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists`, as the IRQL is raised to DISPATCH before calling it (and obviously lowered to whatever it was afterward), and that does appear in the output of `!dpcwatchdog` shown below. This is done due to a workaround for another bug explained here:

[IRQL_UNEXPECTED_VALUE BSOD after NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194617/irql-unexpected-value-bsod-after-ndisfindicatereceivenetbufferlists)

Now this is the bugcheck:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period.
Arg3: fffff805422fb320, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
    additional information regarding the cumulative timeout
Arg4: 0000000000000000
```

```
STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x1846b2
nt!KiUpdateRunTime+0x5d
nt!KiUpdateTime+0x4a1
nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x2e3
nt!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0xe2
nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x2c
nt!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x5c
wanarp!WanNdisReceivePackets+0x4bb
ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen+0x141
ndis!ndisMTopReceiveNetBufferLists+0x3f0e4
ndis!ndisCallReceiveHandler+0x61
ndis!ndisInvokeNextReceiveHandler+0x1df
ndis!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x104
ndiswan!IndicateRecvPacket+0x596
ndiswan!ApplyQoSAndIndicateRecvPacket+0x20b
ndiswan!ProcessPPPFrame+0x16f
ndiswan!ReceivePPP+0xb3
ndiswan!ProtoCoReceiveNetBufferListChain+0x442
ndis!ndisMCoIndicateReceiveNetBufferListsToNetBufferLists+0xf6
ndis!NdisMCoIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x11
raspptp!CallIndicateReceived+0x210
raspptp!CallProcessRxNBLs+0x199
ndis!ndisDispatchIoWorkItem+0x12
nt!IopProcessWorkItem+0x135
nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x105
nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  wanarp!WanNdisReceivePackets+4bb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: wanarp

IMAGE_NAME:  wanarp.sys
```

And this following is the output of `!dpcwatchdog`, but I still can't find what is causing this bugcheck, and can't find which function is consuming too much time in DISPATCH level which is causing this bugcheck. Although I think this could be related to some spin locking done by wanarp? Could this be a bug with wanarp? Note that we don't use any spinlocking in our driver, and us raising the IRQL should not cause any issue as it is actually very common for indication in Ndis to be done at IRQL DISPATCH.

So How can I find the root cause of this bugcheck? There are no other third party LWF in the ndis stack.

```
3: kd> !dpcwatchdog 

All durations are in seconds (1 System tick = 15.625000 milliseconds)

Circular Kernel Context Logger history: !logdump 0x2
DPC and ISR stats: !intstats /d

--------------------------------------------------
CPU#0
--------------------------------------------------
Current DPC: No Active DPC

Pending DPCs:
----------------------------------------
CPU Type      KDPC       Function

dpcs: no pending DPCs found

--------------------------------------------------
CPU#1
--------------------------------------------------
Current DPC: No Active DPC

Pending DPCs:
----------------------------------------
CPU Type      KDPC       Function
 1: Normal  : 0xfffff80542220e00 0xfffff805418dbf10 nt!PpmCheckPeriodicStart
 1: Normal  : 0xfffff80542231d40 0xfffff8054192c730 nt!KiBalanceSetManagerDeferredRoutine
 1: Normal  : 0xffffbd0146590868 0xfffff80541953200 nt!KiEntropyDpcRoutine


DPC Watchdog Captures Analysis for CPU #1.
   DPC Watchdog capture size: 641 stacks.
   Number of unique stacks: 1.
   No common functions detected!

The captured stacks seem to indicate that only a single DPC or generic function is the culprit.
Try to analyse what other processors were doing at the time of the following reference capture:
CPU #1 DPC Watchdog Reference Stack (#0 of 641) - Time: 16 Min 17 Sec 984.38 mSec
 # RetAddr           Call Site
00 fffff805418d8991  nt!KiUpdateRunTime+0x5D 
01 fffff805418d2803  nt!KiUpdateTime+0x4A1 
02 fffff805418db1c2  nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x2E3 
03 fffff80541808a45  nt!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0xE2 
04 fffff805419fab9a  nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xA5 
05 fffff805419fb107  nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xFA 
06 fffff805418a9a9c  nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37 
07 fffff805418da3cc  nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x2C 
08 fffff8054fa614cb  nt!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x5C 
09 fffff80546ba1eb1  wanarp!WanNdisReceivePackets+0x4BB 
0a fffff80546be0b84  ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen+0x141 
0b fffff80546ba7ef1  ndis!ndisMTopReceiveNetBufferLists+0x3F0E4 
0c fffff80546bddfef  ndis!ndisCallReceiveHandler+0x61 
0d fffff80546ba4a94  ndis!ndisInvokeNextReceiveHandler+0x1DF 
0e fffff8057c32d17e  ndis!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x104 
0f fffff8057c30d6c7  ndiswan!IndicateRecvPacket+0x596 
10 fffff8057c32d56b  ndiswan!ApplyQoSAndIndicateRecvPacket+0x20B 
11 fffff8057c32d823  ndiswan!ProcessPPPFrame+0x16F 
12 fffff8057c308e62  ndiswan!ReceivePPP+0xB3 
13 fffff80546c5c006  ndiswan!ProtoCoReceiveNetBufferListChain+0x442 
14 fffff80546c5c2d1  ndis!ndisMCoIndicateReceiveNetBufferListsToNetBufferLists+0xF6 
15 fffff8057c2b0064  ndis!NdisMCoIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x11 
16 fffff8057c2b06a9  raspptp!CallIndicateReceived+0x210 
17 fffff80546bd9dc2  raspptp!CallProcessRxNBLs+0x199 
18 fffff80541899645  ndis!ndisDispatchIoWorkItem+0x12 
19 fffff80541852b65  nt!IopProcessWorkItem+0x135 
1a fffff80541871d25  nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x105 
1b fffff80541a00778  nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55 
1c ----------------  nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28 

--------------------------------------------------
CPU#2
--------------------------------------------------
Current DPC: No Active DPC

Pending DPCs:
----------------------------------------
CPU Type      KDPC       Function
 2: Normal  : 0xffffbd01467f0868 0xfffff80541953200 nt!KiEntropyDpcRoutine


DPC Watchdog Captures Analysis for CPU #2.
   DPC Watchdog capture size: 641 stacks.
   Number of unique stacks: 1.
   No common functions detected!

The captured stacks seem to indicate that only a single DPC or generic function is the culprit.
Try to analyse what other processors were doing at the time of the following reference capture:
CPU #2 DPC Watchdog Reference Stack (#0 of 641) - Time: 16 Min 17 Sec 984.38 mSec
 # RetAddr           Call Site
00 fffff805418d245a  nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x453 
01 fffff80541808a45  nt!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine+0x1A 
02 fffff805419fab9a  nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xA5 
03 fffff805419fb107  nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xFA 
04 fffff805418a9a9c  nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37 
05 fffff805418a9a68  nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x2C 
06 fffff8054fa611cb  nt!KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc+0x88 
07 fffff80546ba1eb1  wanarp!WanNdisReceivePackets+0x1BB 
08 fffff80546be0b84  ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen+0x141 
09 fffff80546ba7ef1  ndis!ndisMTopReceiveNetBufferLists+0x3F0E4 
0a fffff80546bddfef  ndis!ndisCallReceiveHandler+0x61 
0b fffff80546be3a81  ndis!ndisInvokeNextReceiveHandler+0x1DF 
0c fffff80546ba804e  ndis!ndisFilterIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x3C611 
0d fffff8054e384d77  ndis!NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x6E 
0e fffff8054e3811a9  ourdriver+0x4D70 
0f fffff80546ba7d40  ourdriver+0x11A0 
10 fffff8054182a6b5  ndis!ndisDummyIrpHandler+0x100 
11 fffff80541c164c8  nt!IofCallDriver+0x55 
12 fffff80541c162c7  nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1A8 
13 fffff80541c15646  nt!IopXxxControlFile+0xC67 
14 fffff80541a0aab5  nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56 
15 ----------------  nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25 

--------------------------------------------------
CPU#3
--------------------------------------------------
Current DPC: No Active DPC

Pending DPCs:
----------------------------------------
CPU Type      KDPC       Function

dpcs: no pending DPCs found
```

Target machine version: `Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP` (4 procs)

Also note that we also pass the `NDIS_RECEIVE_FLAGS_DISPATCH_LEVEL` flag to the `NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists`, if the current IRQL is dispatch.

Edit1:
This is also the output of `!locks` and `!qlocks` and `!ready`, And the contention count on one of the resources is 49135, is this normal or too high? Could this be related to our issue? The threads that are waiting on it or own it are for normal processes such as chrome, csrss, etc.

```
3: kd> !kdexts.locks 
**** DUMP OF ALL RESOURCE OBJECTS ****
KD: Scanning for held locks.

Resource @ nt!ExpTimeRefreshLock (0xfffff80542219440)    Exclusively owned
    Contention Count = 17
     Threads: ffffcf8ce9dee640-01<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks.....

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cde7f59f8    Shared 1 owning threads
    Contention Count = 62
     Threads: ffffcf8ce84ec080-01<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks...............................................................................................

Resource @ 0xffffcf8ce08d0890    Exclusively owned
    Contention Count = 49135
    NumberOfSharedWaiters = 1
    NumberOfExclusiveWaiters = 6
     Threads: ffffcf8cf18e3080-01<*> ffffcf8ce3faf080-01    

     Threads Waiting On Exclusive Access:
              ffffcf8ceb6ce080       ffffcf8ce1d20080       ffffcf8ce77f1080       ffffcf8ce92f4080       
              ffffcf8ce1d1f0c0       ffffcf8ced7c6080       
KD: Scanning for held locks.

Resource @ 0xffffcf8ce08d0990    Shared 1 owning threads
     Threads: ffffcf8cf18e3080-01<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Resource @ 0xffffcf8ceff46350    Shared 1 owning threads
     Threads: ffffcf8ce6de8080-01<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cf0cade50    Exclusively owned
    Contention Count = 3
     Threads: ffffcf8ce84ec080-01<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks.........................

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cf0f76180    Shared 1 owning threads
     Threads: ffffcf8ce83dc080-02<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cf1875cb0    Shared 1 owning threads
    Contention Count = 3
     Threads: ffffcf8ce89db040-02<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks.

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cf18742d0    Shared 1 owning threads
     Threads: ffffcf8cee5e1080-02<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks....................................................................................

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cdceeece0    Shared 2 owning threads
    Contention Count = 4
     Threads: ffffcf8ce3a1c080-01<*> ffffcf8ce5625040-01<*> 

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cdceeed48    Shared 1 owning threads
     Threads: ffffcf8ce5625043-02<*> *** Actual Thread ffffcf8ce5625040
KD: Scanning for held locks...

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cf1d377d0    Exclusively owned
     Threads: ffffcf8cf0ff3080-02<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks....

Resource @ 0xffffcf8cf1807050    Exclusively owned
     Threads: ffffcf8ce84ec080-01<*> 
KD: Scanning for held locks......
245594 total locks, 13 locks currently held
3: kd> !qlocks 
Key: O = Owner, 1-n = Wait order, blank = not owned/waiting, C = Corrupt

                       Processor Number
    Lock Name         0  1  2  3

KE   - Unused Spare             
MM   - Unused Spare             
MM   - Unused Spare             
MM   - Unused Spare             
CC   - Vacb                     
CC   - Master                   
EX   - NonPagedPool             
IO   - Cancel                   
CC   - Unused Spare             
IO   - Vpb                      
IO   - Database                 
IO   - Completion               
NTFS - Struct                   
AFD  - WorkQueue                
CC   - Bcb                      
MM   - NonPagedPool       


3: kd> !ready
KSHARED_READY_QUEUE fffff8053f1ada00: (00) ****------------------------------------------------------------
SharedReadyQueue fffff8053f1ada00: No threads in READY state
Processor 0: No threads in READY state
Processor 1: Ready Threads at priority 15
    THREAD ffffcf8ce9dee640  Cid 2054.2100  Teb: 000000fab7bca000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 READY on processor 1
Processor 2: No threads in READY state
Processor 3: No threads in READY state




3: kd> dt nt!_ERESOURCE 0xffffcf8ce08d0890
   +0x000 SystemResourcesList : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffcf8c`e08d0610 - 0xffffcf8c`e08cf710 ]
   +0x010 OwnerTable       : 0xffffcf8c`ee6e8210 _OWNER_ENTRY
   +0x018 ActiveCount      : 0n1
   +0x01a Flag             : 0xf86
   +0x01a ReservedLowFlags : 0x86 ''
   +0x01b WaiterPriority   : 0xf ''
   +0x020 SharedWaiters    : 0xffffae09`adcae8e0 Void
   +0x028 ExclusiveWaiters : 0xffffae09`a9aabea0 Void
   +0x030 OwnerEntry       : _OWNER_ENTRY
   +0x040 ActiveEntries    : 1
   +0x044 ContentionCount  : 0xbfef
   +0x048 NumberOfSharedWaiters : 1
   +0x04c NumberOfExclusiveWaiters : 6
   +0x050 Reserved2        : (null) 
   +0x058 Address          : (null) 
   +0x058 CreatorBackTraceIndex : 0
   +0x060 SpinLock         : 0
3: kd> dx -id 0,0,ffffcf8cdcc92040 -r1 (*((ntkrnlmp!_OWNER_ENTRY *)0xffffcf8ce08d08c0))
(*((ntkrnlmp!_OWNER_ENTRY *)0xffffcf8ce08d08c0))                 [Type: _OWNER_ENTRY]
    [+0x000] OwnerThread      : 0xffffcf8cf18e3080 [Type: unsigned __int64]
    [+0x008 ( 0: 0)] IoPriorityBoosted : 0x0 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008 ( 1: 1)] OwnerReferenced  : 0x0 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008 ( 2: 2)] IoQoSPriorityBoosted : 0x1 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008 (31: 3)] OwnerCount       : 0x1 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008] TableSize        : 0xc [Type: unsigned long]
3: kd> dx -id 0,0,ffffcf8cdcc92040 -r1 ((ntkrnlmp!_OWNER_ENTRY *)0xffffcf8cee6e8210)
((ntkrnlmp!_OWNER_ENTRY *)0xffffcf8cee6e8210)                 : 0xffffcf8cee6e8210 [Type: _OWNER_ENTRY *]
    [+0x000] OwnerThread      : 0x0 [Type: unsigned __int64]
    [+0x008 ( 0: 0)] IoPriorityBoosted : 0x1 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008 ( 1: 1)] OwnerReferenced  : 0x1 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008 ( 2: 2)] IoQoSPriorityBoosted : 0x1 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008 (31: 3)] OwnerCount       : 0x0 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x008] TableSize        : 0x7 [Type: unsigned long]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I've tracked this down to an OS bug: there's a deadlock in wanarp. This issue appears to affect every version of the OS going back to Windows Vista.

I've filed internal issue task.ms/42393356 to track this: if you have a Microsoft support contract, your rep can get you status updates on that issue.

Meanwhile, you can partially work around this issue by either:

- Indicating 1 packet at a time (`NumberOfNetBufferLists==1`); or
- Indicating on a single CPU at a time

The bug in wanarp is exposed when 2 or more CPUs collectively process 3 or more NBLs at the same time. So either workaround would avoid the trigger conditions.

Depending on how much bandwidth you're pushing through this network interface, those options could be rather bad for CPU/battery/throughput. So please try to avoid pessimizing batching unless it's really necessary. (For example, you could make this an option that's off-by-default, unless the customer specifically uses wanarp.)

Note that you cannot fully prevent the issue yourself. Other drivers in the stack, including NDIS itself, have the right to group packets together, which would have the side effect re-batching the packets that you carefully un-batched. However, I believe that you can make a statistically significant dent in the crashes if you just indicate 1 NBL at a time, or indicate multiple NBLs on 1 CPU at a time.

Sorry this is happening to you again! wanarp is... a very old codebase.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering Jeffrey. But one thing tho: I believe we already indicate on a single CPU at a time, because we have a single user-mode thread that sends the LWF driver the packets, and in the driver we chain them together and indicate them together. So Aren't we Indicating on a single CPU at a time already, considering that we have a single user-mode thread?

Comment: Although I forgot that we also indicate in our receive callback on rare cases that do not need user-mode processing, so I assume when we are unlucky and we Indicate in our receive callback and in our irp_mj_device_control at the same time on different CPU core, and the user is using wanarp, then this happens? If so, then what is the proper/optimized way to tell NDIS to call our receive callback on a specific CPU core, or force NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists to use a specific core?